# Cannot pass immutable value of type 'NSObject' as inout argument

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, immutability, inout

This should work, but I've got no clue why it doesn't. The code is self-explanatory.

```
class Themer {

   class func applyTheme(_ object: inout NSObject) {
      //do theming
   }
}
```

And I apply theme to the button like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        Themer.applyTheme(&button)
    }
```

The button object is a variable, yet the compiler throws an error.

Comment: Use `UIView` instead of `NSObject`

Comment: Think about what would happen if `applyTheme(_:)` set `object` to an `NSNumber` instance (which inherits from `NSObject`, so is legal) ;)

Comment: you cannot pass a variable of Type X to an inout of some parent of X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since button is an object, this syntax

```
Themer.applyTheme(&button)
```

means that you want to change the reference to that object. But this is not what you want. You want to change the referenced object so you simply need to write

```
Themer.applyTheme(button)
```

Finally you also don't need the `inout` annotation

```
class Themer {
    class func applyTheme(_ object: AnyObject) {
        //do theming
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Themer.applyTheme(self.button)

    }
}
```

### But...

However, what should your `applyTheme` method do? It receives `AnyObject` and then what? You could make it a little but more specific and use a `UIView` as param

```
class Themer {
    class func applyTheme(view: UIView) {
        //do theming
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Themer.applyTheme(view: button)
    }
}
```

Now you have a chance to write meaningful code inside `Themer.applyTheme`.

Comment: Note that you *can* use `inout` with reference types – it allows the function to change the reference of the variable that's passed to it. Although you're right that it's probably not what OP wants.

Comment: @Hamish You are right, I'll correct my statement. Thank you!

Comment: I knew I was doing something wrong when I found no questions like mine though this should be common. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

inout is for the case that you want to change the reference, that is replace one object with another object. That's a very, very, very bad thing to do with an IBOutlet. That button is used in a view, connected up to lots of things, and if you change the variable, all hell will break lose.

Apart from that, listen to appzYourLife.